# Can we put one more helpful link to our How To Ask page?

Tags: discussion, support

[Leif Singer](https://leif.me), design & research team lead for [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/), [tweeted](https://twitter.com/lsinger/status/922825761375080449) a research paper as [How to Ask for Technical Help? Evidence-based Guidelines for Writing Questions on Stack Overflow](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1710/1710.04692.pdf) and [Stack Overflow official Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) retweeted it.

[image]

Would it better to put it as a link on "additional resources" part (the bottom) of the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page?

Comment: Not sure how approachable a research paper is for people who actually need help for asking good questions.

Comment: A 44- no wait, a  33-page well-referenced PDF is helpful now?  I mean I *get* it, but even *I* don't want to read that entire thing.

Comment: I  made this joke before: *guidance needs to fit in a tweet, anything more verbose and you've lost their attention*. I mean even [`/questions/ask/advice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) isn't helping much, is it?

Comment: @rene: Your comment is too long. You lost me at /questions/ask...

Comment: `s/uppercase/inline code formatting/`

Comment: @Makoto I thought [this link](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) _can_ be on "How To Ask" page (which makes 28-page word when I copy paste it), this wouldn't be a problem.